# How to correctly forward to another view after update

Tags: php, laravel

I've got quite a few forms within my web application. However, I've noticed that once I've completed a post and forwarded the user to the new page, the URL is still that of the update. And as such is the user was the refresh the page, it resubmits the request.

Below is how I'm handling my forwarding.

```php
public function update(Request $request, Wedding $wedding, User $user)
{
    $user->attending = ($request->attending != null);
    $user->save();

    $message = "Sorry to hear you won't make it!";

    if ($user->attending) {
        $message = 'Welcome to the party pal!';
    }

    return view('pages.guest.rsvp')
        ->with(compact('wedding'))
        ->with(compact('user'))
        ->with('success', $message);
}
```

So, once the "return view..." is executed, the user is forward to the given view which is fine, but it allows them to refresh the page and resubmit the same post.

I've used the following code as an alternative test.

```php
return redirect('/{$wedding->id}/rsvp')
    ->with(compact('wedding'))
    ->with(compact('user'))
    ->with('success', $message);
```

However, this doesn't seem to pass through the variables (such as the 'success' message). Also, this relies on my manually typing out the URL each time, with all of the URL parameters, whereas just telling it which view to use seems a lot cleaner.

---

UPDATE: In response to Максим Степанов I've updated my route with the following:

```php
Route::get('rsvp', 'Guest\MenuController@index')->name('rsvp');
```

Which does work (thank you for that), however, I'm now redirecting like this:

```php
return redirect()
        ->route('rsvp', ['wedding' => $wedding])
        ->with('success', $message);
```

While the redirect does work, the success message doesn't seem to be working, the message is caught via this:

```php
@if (isset($success))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{$success}}
    </div>
@endif
```

I've searched for guidance on why the items in the "->with(..." aren't going through with redirects, but I can't find anyone having this issue - I'm assuming it's with something I'm doing. I just can't figure out what.

Comment: You can just flash the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route) helper with the [`redirect`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-redirect) helper to specify the route name you wish to go to:

```
return redirect()->route('your.route.name')->with([...]);
```

**Note:** This requires you to have named your route e.g.

```
Route::get('/test', 'SomeController@index')->name('your.route.name');
```

or you can pass the URL directly to `redirect`.

When you call `view` on its own, although it loads the actual `view`, the corresponding controller is not fired because the controller is tied to the request, not the actual view.

---

The [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) helper creates a flash session item, as such, you will need to, in your blade, access it through the [`session`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-session) helper and not as a direct variable:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having issues accessing the variables you are trying to pass using the `with` method is that the `with` method flashes the data into the session instead of passing it directly through to the view. See the following reference.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

So into order to access the variables in your view, you can just pull the success message from the session data

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
Route::get('/{$wedding}/rsvp', 'UpdateController@update')->name('wedding');
```

Controller:

```
return redirect()->route('wedding', ['id' => $wedding->id])->with('success', $message);
```

or

```
return redirect()->action(
    'UpdateController@update', ['wedding' => $wedding]
)->with('success', $message);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've updated my question after trying your suggestion, seems to be an issue with the success message going through still, don't happen to have any ideas do you?